# Windows 7 on 1st Gen Macbook Pro (Q4-2008), power management problems

Tags: windows-7, macbook, boot-camp, power-management

I have the first generation macbook pro, purchased Q4 2008. I've been trying to run Windows 7 and can get it all installed great with the BootCamp 3.1 64 bit drivers however ... power management isn't great.

The screen and keyboard don't automatically dim - the laptop gets too hot.

I noticed on some newer macbook pros that windows 7 works perfectly and the above doesn't happen. Does anyone know if there really is a hardware issue with this 1st gen or is there some firmware update I can use to fix this?

Thanks!